# Loop stopping halfway ansi C

Tags: c, for-loop, codeblocks

I have the following code:

```
void toCapital(char name[], int size){
    int i = 0;
    char *wholeName = name;

    for (i = 0; i < size ; i++){
        wholeName[i] = toupper(wholeName[i]);
        printf("%c", wholeName[i]);
    }
}

main()
{
    char miNombre[] = "Jason Martin Marx";
    toCapital(miNombre, sizeof(miNombre));
}
```

And the output is:

```
JASON MA
```

This code takes a char array and converts all the strings inside into upper case. However, for some reason it stops halfway. Even if i increase the number of times to run the loop, it just adds gibberish at the end instead of the following letter.

If i was to edit the array into something like "Jason Martin Marx Jason Martin Marx" (doubling the string size) then it would print out the upper cased string once as "JASON MARTIN MARX" but not the second time.

Here is the whole code as requested:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void myName(char name[], int size){
int i;
for (i = 0; i < size -1; i++){
    char currentLetter = name[i];
    if (currentLetter == 'a' || currentLetter == 'e' || currentLetter == 'i' || currentLetter == 'o' || currentLetter == 'u' ||
        currentLetter == 'A' || currentLetter == 'E' || currentLetter == 'I' || currentLetter == 'O' || currentLetter == 'U'){
        printf("Character [%c] located at position %i is a vowel\n", currentLetter, i);
    }
    else if (currentLetter == ' '){
        printf("Character [%c] located at position %i is a space\n", currentLetter, i);
    }
    else if (currentLetter == '$' || currentLetter == '%'){
        printf("Character [%c] located at position %i is a symbol\n", currentLetter, i);
    }
    else{
        printf("Character [%c] located at position %i is a consonant\n", currentLetter, i);
    }
}
}

void pyramidA(char name[], int size){
int i;
char *wholeName = name;
int pointer = size-1;
char spaces[80] = "";
for (i = 0; i < (size / 2) ; i++){
    printf("%i %s [%s] \n", pointer, spaces, wholeName);
    wholeName++; ///erases first letter
    wholeName[strlen(wholeName) - 1] = '\0'; /// erases last letter
    pointer = pointer - 2;
    strcat(spaces," ");
    }
}

void toUpper(char name[], int size){
    int i = 0;
    char *wholeName = name;
    printf("%s", wholeName);

    for (i = 0; i < size ; i++){
        wholeName[i] = toupper(wholeName[i]);
        printf("%c", wholeName[i]);
    }

}

main()
{
    char miNombre[] = "Jason $ Martin % Marx ";
    myName(miNombre, sizeof(miNombre));
    printf("\n");
    pyramidA(miNombre, sizeof(miNombre));
    printf("\n");
    toUpper(miNombre, sizeof(miNombre));

}
```

Comment: use strlen(), not sizeof(). Also, use strdup() if you want to make a copy of a string. All you've done with `char *wholeName = name;` is create a redundant pointer to `name`. You are destroying your input.

Comment: `strlen` is what you're looking for

Comment: Looks good. I'm stumped.

Comment: `sizeof` should work too.

Comment: code looks ok; is it really the code shows the broken behavior?

Comment: Ok so I found out something, i printed out wholeName and it only has half of the string. For some reason the method is only recieving half of the whole string.

Comment: @JasonMarks The code in the question works just fine for me; show the code with the problem…

Comment: Agreed. Are we seeing all the code?

Comment: @AlexReynolds The whole code is in the main post

Comment: @Arkku The whole code is in the main post

Comment: Maybe some stack corruption/buffer overflow? results could be very platform-dependent in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is quite simply that you are modifying the string yourself. You probably think that assigning a pointer to another pointer creates a copy, but it doesn't:

```
char *wholeName = name;
// …
wholeName[strlen(wholeName) - 1] = '\0'; // <- modifies string in 'name'
```

If you want a temporary copy of `name` in `wholeName`, you must duplicate it, e.g.:

```
char *wholeName = malloc(size);
name = strcpy(wholeName, name);

// at the end of the function:
free(name);
```

It would be good style to check the return value of `malloc`. Also, you must `free` the same pointer that was returned by `malloc`, and since you do `wholeName++` inside the loop I recycled the `name` pointer above to store the starting position. (The naming of the pointers is now quite misleading.)

Comment: That only removes the last letter from wholeName.

Comment: @JasonMarks You only have one string that you are accessing through the pointer `wholeName`, so you are actually modifying `miNombre` in `main` when you modify `wholeName` in `pyramidA`.

Comment: @JasonMarks yes; it removes the last letter from wholeName `size / 2` times which cuts the name in the middle

Comment: @Jason Marks That not just remove letter from string, you "NULL terminated" the string, so next time when you call toUpper(), the printf string will just stop at where you assign '\0' before. So you won't see entire string at that printf("%s", wholeName).

Comment: @Arkku how would you replace the wholeName++ to remove the first letter then?

Comment: @JasonMarks Answer edited so that you don't have to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can do on gcc is create the output of the preprocessor by compiling with the -E option.  There might be something going on that is not obvious by looking at the code before compiling.  I ran your code and the output is not the same as your are getting. gcc -E foo.c -o foo.i.  Edit foo.i and see if your code has been morphed by the preprocessor in any way.

```
================ output below ==================
JASON MARTIN MARX
```

Comment: well, at least for my test, sizeof() do reflect the length.

Comment: yes miNombre is an array not a pointer. i ran his code and it worked for me, so there must be something else going on in his environment.

Answer (score 0):

The result may be compiler-dependent:

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -pedantic test.c 
test.c: In function 'toCapital':
test.c:6:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'toupper' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
test.c:7:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'printf' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
test.c:7:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf' [enabled by default]
test.c: At top level:
test.c:11:1: warning: return type defaults to 'int' [enabled by default]
```

Here's a result from testing the resulting binary on my end:

```
bash-3.2$ ./a.out 
JASON MARTIN MARX^@bash-3.2$
```

Other than the warnings, I think using `sizeof()` on an array declared on the stack should be okay. I think your problem is elsewhere, but I don't know where.

**EDIT**

Now that we have all the code, your function `pyramidA()` is manipulating the contents of `miNombre`. That's why your string is truncated.

Use `strcpy()` within the functions to work with a copy of the string `miNombre`. This leaves `miNombre` unchanged.

Comment: probably cause by missing toupper() prototype but not related to the problem